# Make css background image (svg) responsive

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to use a SVG file as background image (css).

Here is my SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="428" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->

 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect fill="none" id="canvas_background" height="102" width="430" y="-1" x="-1"/>
  <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
   <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="1" x="1" height="400" width="580"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <text stroke="#000" transform="matrix(1.22606 0 0 1.22606 -24.7533 -46.6879)" opacity="0.3" font-style="italic" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="left" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_1" y="87.150366" x="22.228393" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">Hello world!</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I encoded it with http://b64.io and used it like this:

```
#new-hello-world {
  background-image: url(…);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Now my problem is that the SVG is not responsive. How can I solve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I already tried to make the `svg` width and height 100% but that did not work.

Comment: Your `svg` code is missing the element with id `#gridpattern`. Please post the entire code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, but actually, this is the entire code. I used this editor: [editor.method.ac](http://editor.method.ac).

Comment: Then you should remove the `url(#gridpattern)`, since there is no pattern in your code defined and replace it with some color.

Comment: I think this is because the background of the `rect` is transparent.

Comment: This is how you make it responsive:---> http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/XJNRBW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `<svg>` element a viewBox attribute e.g. `viewBox = "0 0 428 100"` although   chipChocolate.py's suggestion of `viewBox="0 0 580 400"` might work better depending on exactly what you want to see.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `viewBox="0 0 580 400"`?

Comment: Because he is using `width="580"` and `height="400"` for the `rect`.